# How to convert .NET dll to unsigned char array to use it from c++

Tags: c++

I have .net dll, i want to convert its content to char array,
result will be like this

```
int Length=10;
unsigned char MyArray[Length] =
{
    0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00
};
```

for dll this Length may be for example 300000. Do You know any software or other way to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what your requirement is. Do you wish you read a file (.dll) into a char array? and do you wish to do this in C++?

Comment: And what is it you want to do with the char array when you've read it in?

Answer (score 1):

http://jonripley.com/windows/Software/bin2h/

[http://www.koders.com/python/](http://www.koders.com/python/fid7D3C25FE9FDE363F1574AFFB20DB0C0F1532BAE3.aspx?s=md5)

or google "bin2h" for others.

Comment: @Tim: could you tell us how you were able to understand the question?

Comment: I don't know, it seemed apparent, I just read it literally.  An odd request with a DLL, but whatever.  Any doubt about whether I understood the question was eliminated by the example size of 300000 and the example data, which starts with 0x4d, 0x5a or "MZ", which is the first two bytes of all PE images (EXE, DLL, etc.) on Windows.